# Salesforce lightning case lookup autocomplete

Tags: salesforce, lightning

How to enable lookup/autocomplete feature in cases. I am doing a migration from classic to lightning. In classic this feature is enabled. I am new to salesforce. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to try and give it a crack at building something before asking someone to just build something for you from scratch.

alas, [pozil](https://github.com/pozil) has built a slds looking lookup component. Can find it [here](https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup-lwc).

It might be a bit overkill for your needs, but would be a solid start to building one yourself.